# Printing a UTF-32 character to terminal

Tags: c++, unicode, glfw, utf-32

I'm reading user input from GLFW using callbacks (set using glfwSetCharCallback) according to this page:
http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input.html#input_char

The callback function recieves the pressed key as a 32-bit unsigned int. How can I convert this to something that I can print on my screen? I've tried both codecvt from C++11 and the ICU library, but couldn't get anything to print readable characters to my terminal.

This is the code of my callback function:

```
void InputManager::charInputCallback(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int key)
    {
        UErrorCode errorStatus = U_ZERO_ERROR; //initialize to no error
        UConverter *utf32toUnicode = ucnv_open("UTF-32", &errorStatus); //create converter utf-32 <=> Unicode
        if(U_FAILURE(errorStatus))
            std::cout << u_errorName(errorStatus) << std::endl;
        UChar unicode[10] = {0};
        ucnv_toUChars(utf32toUnicode, unicode, 10, (char*)key, 4, &errorStatus); // this fails with an U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
        if(U_FAILURE(errorStatus))
            std::cout << u_errorName(errorStatus) << std::endl;

        std::cout << unicode << std::endl;
    }
```

If I do nothing to the input (key), nothing's shown at all. Just a blank line.

Comment: What characters are in question? What conversion did you try? What operating system are you on?

Comment: The characters I'm looking for are the actual letters (unless I'm missunderstanding the function), i.e. pressing 'e' on the keyboard sends the character 'e' to the callback method. As I said: I've tried codecvt (from this example code http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt ) and using the ICU library. With ICU I tried creating two converters. One from UTF-32 to Unicode, and finally from Unicode to UTF-8. However, since ucnv_toUChars takes char* as input, and explicitly typecasting the unsigned int didn't work. I can recreate the deleted code if you want me to.

Comment: Also, I'm using Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by Unicode? And is your Linux terminal window set up to handle UTF-8? ICU can convert, I believe, UTF-32 directly to UTF-8. It would help if you posted your conversion code.

Comment: The terminal should be set up for UTF-8 by default, shouldn't it? I've added my code in the post above (also commented the line that causes the ICU error). Am I feeding ucnv_toUChars bad data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling ucnv_toUChars(), which converts an 8-bit string to Unicode.  But you need to go the other way, and convert your Unicode string to 8-bit, such as UTF-8.  I would use the UnicodeString class, which has a constructor taking UTF-32, and a method toUTF8String().

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Thank you very much!